# On solaris 8, moved ld.so.1 file to another name, tried to move it back with builtins and get cannot create

Tags: solaris

Moved the ld.so.1 file to another named file in /usr/lib on a Solaris 8 system. As soon as I enter the system I get the :root> prompt., no longer login and password. 
Tried working with the builtins and tried this from another post:

echo -nE "'< newnamedfile'" > ld.so.1

Receive: ld.so.1 cannot create

This is a remote system, anything possible..short of having the remote site boot with the system disk and try to recover? Any simple magic as to why I cannot create? I know I pretty much lost access to most everything except builtins.

Thanks

Comment: The file `ld.so.1` that you wrongly renamed is the binary interpreter. Try running this `/usr/lib/wrongname.so /usr/bin/mv /usr/lib/wrongname.so /usr/lib/ld.so.1`, where `/usr/lib/wrongname.so` is the original `ld.so.1`.

Comment: @alvits Nice idea, but from my reading of the question, the OP isn't even getting far enough along to try even that.  Apparently the OS isn't booting at all.

Comment: What kind of system is this?  What is the underlying hardware?  Is the operating system still running, and do you have a working connection and shell prompt on it?

Comment: This is a Sun netra 1125 (sparc based) and indeed no OS is available, simply limited to the built ins. I can echo $SHELL and get bsh. $PATH is minimal and not right. Anyway going to try to boot from SUN disk and get that ld.so.1 file over to where its supposed to be.

Comment: Going to have to try to boot into CD tomorrow, so if any other thoughts as an interim....that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? Did you get an error message when running it?

Comment: "cannot create" may mean the filesystem is mounted read-only.

Comment: There may be some programs you can use in `/sbin` that are statically linked and will work even when there's no dynamic linker.

Comment: Apologize for delay, but we were trying to get to the OK> prompt remotely and have not had success.

Comment: We are able to use builtins, cd, pwd work etc. tried cd to /usr/lib, did a pwd to verify, tried /usr/bin/mv backfile ld.so.1. received: mv: cannot find /usr/lib/ld.so.1 Killed. This is the same error message received trying to execute any command which is not a builtin. (i.e cp, mv, even mount(which is in sbin)... that being cannot find /usr/lib/ld.so.1, followed by killed. Tried a few command is sbin with the same results.

Comment: well, booted to cdrom -s, did a fsck on the c0/t0/d0/s0, repaired errors, and copied my old ld.so.1 to the original ld.so.1. Thendid a boot, 1st error is loadkeys: Cannot map /usr/lib/ld.so.1 Killed, followed by kbd: cfstype:, dsgetdevice: , with the map error on /usr/lib/ld.so.1 file. (we did this several times, same results)  I was hesitant to cp the lib.so.1 file from the CD for the byte count is different from the original. Any thoughts on that? Also, every time we boot, we have to run fsck with the same errors pointing to inode  deailng with ld.so.1!We correct that and do a sync